# How do I call a function in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know this question has been asked over and over, but I can't follow any of the guides I've found.

I'm a total beginner with Access and writing VBA, so I found some code that will help me import A LOT of files into separate tables in Access.

I have tried several variations of putting the code in and calling from a macro or a button...none of them have been successful.

There might be something wrong with the code, but I don't know enough to figure it out. I'm also pretty sure I'm doing something else wrong when trying to call the function. Please help me!

Here's the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function DoImport()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = True

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\folder"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
   strPathFile = strPath & strFile
   strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
         strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

   strFile = Dir()
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: This code is clearly copied off of a website. What line do you get the error on? Have you checked your references with the aforementioned website to make sure that you have the correct libraries enabled?

Comment: Oh yeah, I definitely copied it. The error pops up on Function and End Function once it's placed into a Sub. If Sub/End Sub is in there, and I take the Function parts out, then I don't get an error, but it doesn't work. It tells me "Sub not defined."

Comment: In VBA a procedure can be either a function or a subroutine.  You cannot have a function inside a subroutine.  Or a subroutine inside a function.  Usually you would only create a function if you wanted to return a value so a subroutine or sub in your code example would suffice

Comment: @Mark3308, thanks for the info on subs vs. functions. I have an Access for Dummies book (seriously, I'm very new to this), but there's nothing in there about this stuff. I guess if you're a Dummy, you're not supposed to be trying out VBA!

Answer (score 0):

To call this procedure it either needs to exist in the current form where the button is or reside in a Module of its own.

Because the function does not return a value or have any arguments to call it you would type the following VBA code in a button's On Click event:

```
DoImport
```

If you wish to make sure the code is actually running you can set a breakpoint by pressing F9 on an executable line of code

Or type the word Stop where you want to debug

The code itself will not be very useful until you have made the changes to the literal strings as the code comments suggest

The code itself as it stands is not very reusable so as a next step you should research using arguments so when you call the function at runtime you can supply the folder name and table name et cetera.

The code itself will search a particular folder for Excel files and attempts to import each file into Microsoft Access, using the filename as the table name.

Comment: What you described the code doing is exactly what I need it to do. Also, I should only need to do this huge import once, so reusing the code isn't all that important to me. Your explanation at the beginning did help explain things to me, though. Thanks for that! I'm going to try and figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new Module and pasting the below code into it.  Save it and name it whatever you want.

```
Public Function DoImport(strPath AS String, strTable AS String, _
                         blnHasFieldNames AS Boolean, RemoveFile AS Boolean)
  Dim strFile As String

  strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
  Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, _
                              strPath & strFile, blnHasFieldNames
    if RemoveFile Then Kill strPath & strFile
    strFile = Dir()
  Loop
End Function
```

Then you can call the function via the following:

```
DoImport "C:\imports\Excel\", "MyTableName", True, True
```

This allows you to pass the path, table name, whether the files contain field names and if you want to remove the file after import.  That way you don't have to potentially change the code of the function constantly.